# QTextEdit - implement instant quote, apostrophe and grave accent

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

Most text editors don't show these characters immediately after you type them and merge them with a next character. However, I'm making code editor based on `QPlainTextEdit` for English alphabet only, so I'd like it to be instant.

I've tried to override `keyPressEvent()` and found out that it gets called when I press **shift**, but when I press **quote** key, it doesn't. Now I have a hunch that this behavior is implemented in `eventFilter`.

My question: is there some inconspicuous option that would save me time and code, or some other way that a skilled Qt programmer would take?